# How can I prevent Firefox from using bitmap fonts at certain zoom levels?

Tags: linux, firefox, fonts, zoom, anti-aliasing

In Firefox 3.6 on Ubuntu 9.10, certain sites seem to use bitmap fonts for any fixed-width fonts, but *only* at specific zoom levels. This site and other Stack Exchange sites are among the affected sites, and of course the default zoom level is affected. At unaffected zoom levels, I get the expected smooth curvy fonts. How can I make Firefox use the nice curvy smooth fonts at all zoom levels?

**Edit:** Adding example code for my own reference.

```
This is code. I want it to look smooth and pretty.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems that the problem is that I put some version of Monaco font in ~/.fonts/. So I suppose this is ultimately a duplicate of [Monaco font not antialiased in some GTK apps](https://superuser.com/questions/93924/monaco-font-not-antialiased-in-some-gtk-apps)